# Deriving a composite function

Tags: calculus

A proof in my book gave a derivation with out explaining how it got it. I am trying to understand how exactly how they worked out that derivative

> [image]

I know they used the chain rule but I just dont see how? I'm sure its something simple but if someone could write it out for me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: They used the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule says that the derivative of $a\circ b$ is $(a^{\prime}\circ b)\cdot b^{\prime}$ (provided $a^\prime$ and $b^\prime$ exist).
In your case, $a\equiv f$ and $b(\lambda)\equiv x^{0}+\lambda(x^{1}-x^{0})$.
Note that $a^{\prime}=f^{\prime}$ and $b^{\prime}(\lambda)=x^{1}-x^{0}$, from which the result follows.

Comment: I know this might be a silly notation complaint, but shouldn't f be w.r.t. x^(delta) instead of x?

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to.